# Is there a way to use ARRAYFORMULA to find the most-recent even input of a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**SOLVED EDIT**

Thank you for the help. Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55229070/11222319).

**ORIGINAL POST**

I have made a google sheet to describe the issue I am facing linked here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yK6ZAX8BFnEqiuQO9HIxuY0l62ewDDccj-8EN1r2i2w/edit?usp=sharing).

I will also describe in words, below, the problem I am facing, along with the solutions I have tried.

[image: link to the image of worksheet]

The data of column A are random single-digit (0-9). I would like column B to show the most recent even number from column A, but only up to a specific row. That specific row is the row corresponding to the row of the cell in column B. In other words, in cell B7, I want to find the most recently entered even number of column A, specifically only on the range A2:A7 (A1 contains a column header).

This is actually a pretty simple formula, and I can get the desired outputs by simply checking if the value in a cell in column A is even and then returning the value of that cell if it is, or the output of the cell above if it isn't. So the formula would look something like: ​`=IF(ISEVEN(A7),A7,B6)​`

However, my problem is that the length of the data in column A will be growing as more data are entered, and my current solution of using the fill handle to copy the formula to new cells is inelegant and time-consuming. So my desired solution is to use an array formula entered into the first cell of column B (B2), capable of returning the same value as the other formula. The formula I tried to enter to perform this was the following: ​`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISEVEN(A2:A),A2:A,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A2:A)-1,2))))​`

However, as some of my previous work with arrays has taught me, not all formulas iterate as expected down the array. The formula seems to be able to return the correct output on lines which are already even, but it is unable to return the expected most-recently entered even number for all the other lines. It appears that the formula is not able to appropriately interpret the `​value_if_false`​ argument of the ​`IF`​ formula.

I'm a little new to scripting, so I'm still trying to learn, but I also tried to dabble around with custom functions to no avail. I'm still wet behind the ears when it comes to coding, which is why I've been so lenient on the built-in formulas of Google Sheets, but I fear I may have reached the limit of what Sheets formulas can do.

I am open to trying new approaches, but my only real constraint is that I would really like for this to be a one-touch (or even better no-touch) solution, hope that's not too far beyond the scope of this issue. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

After rubber-ducking the problem here, I went back and tried to use the `OFFSET` formula, hoping I could get it to play nicely with the array formula. Alas, I was unable, but I thought I should at least post my progress here for reference.

[Attempt with offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njBTw.png)

Still working at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a vlookup on the row number seems to work for me

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",vlookup(row(A2:A),{if(iseven(A2:A),row(A2:A)),A2:A},2)))
```

[image]

Note: if there are no even numbers in range for some rows, it will produce #N/A for those rows.